# Custom enum domain in H2 throwing syntax error in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, h2

I'm trying to make a custom ENUM type that I can use across my H2 database. This is the code:

```
CREATE DOMAIN IF NOT EXISTS LICENCE AS ENUM('A','B','C','NONE');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RequiredLicence (
  id BIGINT,
  lic LICENCE,
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Vehicle (id),
  PRIMARY KEY (id, lic)
)
```

I have the H2 SQL dialect enabled in Idea, but it's giving me a syntax error when trying to use the tipe LICENCE

[image]

When I open the H2 Console I can see that the Domain is being created, but the description is pretty vague so I don't even know if it's right.

My question is, am I doing this correctly? Is this just a bug with IntelliJ?

Comment: What's the error that's been generated?

Comment: @MadProgrammer `<type> expected, got LICENCE`

Comment: I have reported the issue for this. Feel free to follow the [DBE-6167](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-6167) for updates.

Comment: @Andrey So it is a bug...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-181.4203.550 and has been reported [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-6167)